# Remove $ from .ToString("{0:C}") formatted number

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Basically I am formatting numbers like this

```
@String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price)
```

The result is $2,320,000.00

My desired result, however, is `2,320,000.00` just without `$`, respectively. How can I attain this, while still taking advantage of .nets localization handling?

**Edit**

and what if i want that change my class so that when ever a person try to get `Price` , he gets this kind of formatted price . Here is my class

```
public class Listing : DomainObject
{   
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Reason behind my edit is that in my first case i have to change on every place where i use place and in second condition it will automatically done everywhere .

Comment: You could create special method as a member of your class..

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `N` instead of `C` as your [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
@String.Format("{0:N}", Model.Price)
```

> "C" or "c"    Currency    Result: A currency value.
>
> 123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
>
> "N" or "n"    Number  Result: Integral and decimal digits, group separators, and a decimal
>
> 1234.567 ("N", en-US) -> 1,234.57

I.e. you were getting a currency symbol because you were *asking* for one.

Comment: Thanks , this works fine , but what about my second question ?

Comment: @user2413182 - doesn't really make sense - if someone is specifying to format a decimal in a string as currency, the currency symbol will be included. Anything else would be deeply surprising, which doesn't make for a good programming experience.

Comment: This changes the behavior of negatives though, they are in parenthesis with {0:C} and show negative sign with {0:N}, so you solve one issue, and possibly present another if you wised to have negatives appear as currency just without the currency symbol.

Comment: As I see in practice right now, "N" gets the NumberDecimalSeparator from CultureInfo, while "C" uses the Currency ones. You can see that by yourself using ru-RU

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why using the "N" format specifier in this example results in 2 decimal digits (as opposed to none, or 3, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

Rather use `{0:F2}` as this will not include Comma',' like in {0:C}.

```
Console.Write("{0:F2}", 2.5); //2.50
Console.Write("{0:F0}", 25);  //25
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to make the Price property a string, and have a backing field of a decimal, then in the getter of your Price property do your string format.

```
private decimal price;

public String Price 
{
   get { return String.Format("{0:N}", price); }
}
```

Then you can use 
`@Model.Price` for display.

Answer (score 2):

Set [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx) to `string.Empty`.

Comment: Your price property is of `decimal`, so it has no format specified at all.