# Can't set display format to 2 decimal places when using mvc6 grid

Tags: c#, format, asp.net-core-mvc, currency, mvcgrid

I need to display some average sums of currency values in my .net core asp mvc project.

I am using [mvc 6 grid](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/) to display the data, and I have tried these solutions:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public double? AverageCost { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.####}")]
public double? AverageCost { get; set; }

[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
public double? AverageCost { get; set; }
```

But still my values are displayed with several decimal places:

[image]

Am I missing something?

I know I can format the columns using the mvc 6 grid, but is there not a way of doing this in the ViewModel?

Note that this is **NOT** a duplicate of the suggested question.. If you actually read the questions you will see that.

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]` for 2 digits https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-currency-c-format-specifier

Comment: _"sums of currency values"_ & _"**double**? AverageCost"_ = bad idea.

Comment: @Fildor Yes I know, but I don't control the database, and the currency values are stored as double?s in there..

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Anyway, fubo's suggestion should do the job.

Comment: @fubo It doesn't seem to work - I guess the grid I'm using disregards `DisplayFormat`

Comment: `[DisplayFormat]` is only respected when you use `DisplayFor()` (or `EditorFor()`)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Column/RenderingValue?

Comment: @Fildor The closest I can get is using `{0:C}`, but that includes the currency symbol, which I don't want

Comment: Have you tried `{0:D2}` then?

Comment: @Fildor I found the answer - its to use `{0:N}`, but some fool marked this as a dupe so I cant post the answer.. how irritating

Comment: Haha, "some fool" ... well, it _is_ a duplicate regarding the DisplayFormat annotation. It just has an additional issue about the format string, which makes it "2 Question in 1" ...

Comment: @Fildor But this question relates to mvc-6 grid, which has different requirements so it absolutely is not a dupe. The solutionn posted as a duplicate will not work here...

Comment: Did you try it? If you did and it did not work for you, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Fildor Well its hard because the posted solution is actually not even relevant... its about dates, and it also relates to using `DisplayFor`, which my question has nothing to do with! The solution is to use `Formatted()` method in the view

Comment: On second reading it really doesn't seem to be related to your issue exactly. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks buddy, hopefully it get re-opened so I can reap some sweet sweet SO point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by using the `Formatted` method and passing in the value `{0:N}` in the view itself:

```
columns.Add(model => model.AverageCost).Titled("AverageCost").Formatted("{0:N}");
```

I found the answer by getting the format string from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541307/remove-from-tostring0c-formatted-number) and finding the `Formatted` method used [here](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Column/Formatting)

This is perfect for me as it displays the values as currency but does not show the currency symbol as `{0:C}` does

Answer (score 2):

In your first line you missed the decimal points after 'C'. it should have been `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]`